# Disjunction logic for complex only in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup Gitlab CI for condition:

- files modified by git push event on directory "spark/**/*"
- **OR** there is a variable $PROJECT == 'spark'

The second condition is for pipelines created by api call (trigger token) which sets the variable.

With AND expression it looks like:

```
  only:
    variables:
      - $PROJECT == 'spark'
    changes:
      - spark/**/*
```

So far my best try is:

```
deploy-spark: &deploy-spark
  # job definition
  only:
    changes:
      - spark/**/*
  except:
    - triggers

deploy-spark-token:
  <<: *deploy-spark
  only:
    variables:
      - $PROJECT == 'spark'
    refs:
      - triggers
  except:
```

But its a lot of boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an elegant solution to this that significantly reduces the boilerplate to implement OR logic.  Whenever I've had to do this I try to separate the "work" from the CI mechanisms to help with maintainability.

Pulling your job definition out into a template, and including that template into each of the deploy jobs helps to keep the interfaces clean.  It means you have one obvious place to change the code that runs, and two places that use that code.  The two deploy jobs don't depend on each other and any changes to one won't inadvertently affect the other.

```
.job-definition: &job-definition
  script:
    - echo "Some script

deploy-spark
  <<: *job-definition
  only:
    changes:
      - spark/**/*
  except:
    - triggers

deploy-spark-token:
  <<: *job-definition
  only:
    variables:
      - $PROJECT == 'spark'
    refs:
      - triggers
```

I know this probably doesn't answer your question, but I hope this helps.

Note that the `.` in `.job-definition` means that the job doesn't run (I like to think of it like hidden files in Linux, adding the dot prefix hides it from CI).